# chmod won't work - no error message

Tags: chmod

Every time I try to change the permissions of a file with `chmod` on my Ubuntu with a command like
`chmod 744 /media/DATEN/Dokumente/Coding/Python/DirFileFuncts.py` it doesn't work. I tried octal and `=rwx` spelling but the output of `ls -l` won't change and I still get errors like: `no Permission` if I try to execute a file.

The strange thing is, that I don't get any error message from `chmod` itself.
Can someone help me?

I tried using `sudo` but it doesn't help. Here is my `mount` result for the partition:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/DATEN type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,fl‌​ush,uhelper=udisks)
```

Comment: Who owns the file? Do you need to `sudo` before changing the permissions?

Comment: As pointed out below and above this comment, type 'mount' and post the results.

Comment: Won't work for NTFS partiton

Comment: @MaxMackie I tried sudo but it doesn't help.
Here my mount result for the partition:
/dev/sdb1 on /media/DATEN type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical behaviour of a filesystem that doesn't understand access permissions - very likely a (V)FAT partition. This is also indicated by the path `/media/...`, which is where removable media is mounted nowadays.

The permission problem occurring when trying to run the script could be caused by the `noexec` mount option (which is understandable safeguard for removable media).

If the above is the case (you can verify that in the `mount` output), you can either run the script by specifying the interpreter, e.g. `python /path/to/script`, or remount the filesystem with the `exec` option  (which generally is a silly workaround from the security point of view).

As a side note, the first option might not work if you your interpreter will try to use `mmap()` to load the file into memory and mark it as executable (because the filesystem layer will refuse that). This is usually the case of the dynamic linker `ld-linux*.so*` (located in `lib` or `/lib64` depending on your system). Python should work though.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, it's in fact a FAT32-Partition and since i can run programs by calling python it seems to be the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Is this non-unix partition? Try to mount the partition with permission option.